# Memory Management iOS dev app doesn't work after a few detail items

Tags: ios, memory, memory-management, uitableview, core-motion

I am working on a project with a tableView controller and the detail views contains CMMotionManager. When i open 5 or 6 detailViews all goes well, but after a while the app goes slow and finally crashes.

On instruments the only leak is on main.m, also I must say that I'm using ARC and I can't dealloc or realese the instances.

Here is the code:
First the table view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.title = @"Movement";//Master View Controller title bar
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"jg_navibar.png"];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image      forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    //Init the array with data
    bodypartsMutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:26];

BodypartData *part1 = [[BodypartData alloc] init];
part1.bodypartname = @"Shoulder";
    part1.movementname = @"Flexion";
    part1.fullimageStartingPosition=[UIImage imageNamed:@"2_shoulder_flexion_end_position.jpg"];
    part1.fullimageEndedPosition=[UIImage imageNamed:@"2_shoulder_flexion_end_position.jpg"];
    part1.thumbimage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"1_shoulder_flexion_landmarks_thumb.jpg"];
[bodypartsMutableArray addObject:part1];

.........
}
```

then the cell:

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyBasicCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    else {
    BodypartData *part = [self.bodypartsMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:part.movementname];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:part.bodypartname];
    cell.imageView.image =part.thumbimage;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

and the the detailViewdid load:

I don't get an error or warning , nothing .Just when i load 6,7 detail views the motionManagers seems to stop working .. just this ... i can go back to the master view and load again and again the detail items but the motion manager doesn't work. here is the code of my detail view

```
@synthesize liveCounterLabel = _liveCounterLabel;
@synthesize resultLabel = _resultLabel;

@synthesize detailItem = _detailItem;
@synthesize imageView = _imageView;
@synthesize calculateButton = _calculateButton;
@synthesize motionManager =_motionManager;
@synthesize selectedImage=_selectedImage;
@synthesize unselectedImage=_unselectedImage;

@synthesize m11started=_m11started;
@synthesize m12started=_m12started;
@synthesize m13started=_m13started;
@synthesize m11ended=_m11ended;
@synthesize m12ended=_m12ended;
@synthesize m13ended=_m13ended;
@synthesize m11=_m11;
@synthesize m12=_m12;
@synthesize m13=_m13;
@synthesize queue=_queue;

@synthesize buttonCounter=_buttonCounter;



#pragma mark - Managing the detail item

- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];

    }
}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    if (self.detailItem) {
        self.imageView.image = [self.detailItem fullimageStartingPosition];
        NSString* longString = [[self.detailItem bodypartname ] stringByAppendingString:    [@" " stringByAppendingString:[self.detailItem movementname]]];
        self.navigationItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:longString];
        //Backround Image code
        [[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage     imageNamed:@"background.jpg"]]];
    }
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    // Init motionManager object and set the Update Interval
    _buttonCounter=0;


    _motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc]init];
    _motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval=1/60; //60 Hz
    [_motionManager startGyroUpdates];

    if (!_queue){
        _queue = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
    }

    if (_motionManager.gyroAvailable) {
        _motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = 1.0/60.0;
        //[_motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
         //                                  withHandler: ^(CMDeviceMotion *motion,    NSError *error)
        [_motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:_queue
                                            withHandler: ^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error)

         {
             CMAttitude *attitude = [[CMAttitude alloc] init];
             attitude=motion.attitude;

             //Calculation with rotationMatrix
             _m11 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", attitude.rotationMatrix.m11];
             _m12 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", attitude.rotationMatrix.m12];
             _m13 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", attitude.rotationMatrix.m13];

     }];
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You should check the result of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. If it's nil, you might be setting properties in a memory part you don't own.

Please refer to this [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW10) (search `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` if you want to skip chapters)

Comment: i changed the code of the dequeueCell ... but nothing changed

Comment: You should update your question with your new code and give details about the Crash message

Answer (score 0):

You need to reuse cells.

Here is how you should do it correctly:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyBasicCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    BodypartData *part = [self.bodypartsMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:part.movementname];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:part.bodypartname];
    cell.imageView.image =part.thumbimage;

    return cell;
}
```

See how we initialize the cell?
We ask the tableview to provide us with an already available cell that was before initialized (so we can reuse the same cell and don't waste memory to allocate a new one).

If the tableView doesn't have a cell available (it's loading for the first time) it will return us nil, so if there is no resubale cell available, we initialize a new one.

Comment: Is it still running out of memory? Are you getting memory warnings in XCode? Please post your crash log

Comment: i updated my question ... but i don't have any warnings or errors.. it just stop counting the rotation rate after i am loading a few detail items ... sometimes ti crashes the the crash shows me the main().(rare)

Comment: Then it's not memory related. The problem lies somewhere else